# How to Export\Import Custom Groups from the the Access 2010 Navigation Pane

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an Access 2010 database front-end which has sadly been corrupted. I have successfully rebuilt it by exporting objects from the corrupted database.

I also had 3 Custom Groups with about 100 shortcut names defined in the Navigation Pane which I would also like to transfer to the new database rather than re-creating them from scratch.

How can I export and then import these custom group definitions and object shortcut names? I'm happy with VBA solutions if that is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access provides an option to import Navigation Pane Groups from your old database, but that option is not prominent.  To find it, begin the import and when you reach the Import Objects dialog, click the "Options >>" button.  Then you will see a Nav Pane Groups check box in the lower left column.

[image]

Comment: Worked Like a Dream! Sorry I took so long to come back to this. Thanks HansUp. It's probably obvious, but to get to this dialog I went via "External Data" and under "Import & Link" I used the "Access" option.

Answer (score 0):

Access doesn't expose any methods to move items (in reality create links) to custom groups. It has to be done through the User Interface.

Comment: Depressing.. So there's no way to get them back except by manually re-creating every shortcut by hand? I thought there must surely be a table somewhere that held all this data...

Comment: I think that information is stored in the MsysNavPane* tables, but have no idea how much effort would be required to extract it.

Comment: @HansUp Extracting it is fairly straightforward: `SELECT MSysNavPaneGroups.Name AS GroupName, MSysNavPaneGroupToObjects.Name AS ObjectName, MSysObjects.Type AS ObjectType FROM MSysNavPaneGroups INNER JOIN (MSysNavPaneGroupToObjects INNER JOIN MSysObjects ON MSysNavPaneGroupToObjects.ObjectID = MSysObjects.Id) ON MSysNavPaneGroups.Id = MSysNavPaneGroupToObjects.GroupID WHERE (((MSysNavPaneGroups.GroupCategoryID)=3));`, but pushing that information into the new database could be problematic. Your answer looks promising (I never noticed that option before).

Comment: Not surprised you figured that out quickly, GT!  BTW, I think that "All Images and Themes" option must be new with Access 2010.  Cheers.

Comment: @HansUp I already had the query built (earlier this morning) but I held off on answering because I didn't see an obvious way to add the groups into the new database. It thought I'd wait and see if a better answer presented itself, and thanks to you it did. :)